# Is it possible to retrieve the generic type when storing in list?

Tags: java, generics

I have to following problem: I have a generic class called `Generic<A>` and some instances of this class lets say

```
Generic<String> foo;
Generic<Double> bar;
```

and i put them into a list like this:

```
List<Generic<?>> list;
list.add(foo);
list.add(bar);
```

now i want to read a method that returns `A`, but instead i only get `Object` as return type, and i know why, because of the ? in the generic type of the list. I also know that `List<Generic<String>>` is a complete different type than `List<Generic<Double>>`... But is there any kind of List Structure or Generic Type argument that i can use to keep the Type of the Generic class the same? Its no problem to cast for me in my program, because i save also a ID for every Instance in my list and now can determinate which type is in there but this seems a little bit dirty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast at some point :(

Answer (score 1):

Is it this what you are looking for?:

```
public <T> T someMethod(List<Generic<T>> list){
      //Return an element from list
}
```

Comment: It is not that dirty XD (You'll have to code the type as well, but the method can be reused).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you whant a common type you should use Object or some class that wrapps your stuff. If you use Object then just check instanceof the object in your method where you do stuff

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the `?` or can you change your code to use `List<Generic<T>>` to keep the type?

If you want to check the type after initialising the `List` with some content, you can use `list.get(0).getClass()` to gain some information but that's not really a nice way to program

Comment: yes i could use the getClass or instanceof but this is not really what i want... think about i would use 20 or more differnet types, that would be a long if, else if list...

Comment: no, unlike instanceof you can save the type with getClass and check it on new instances using a single ==